# having error while association in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have a simple project in which i created a `view`, `controller`,`model`, `migration` using the following syntax:

```
rails g scaffold user name:string contact:string
```

then i created a model only with the following command:

```
rails g model event event_name:string event_place:string
```

then i created association in the models which you can see in the following code.

code of `user.rb` class is following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events


  attr_accessible :contact, :name, :events_attributes

  accepted_nested_attributes_for :events

end
```

code of `event.rb` class is following:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :event_name, :event_place
end
```

the code of the `index.html.erb` is following:

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.contact %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

and i haven't changed anything in my views..... as the scaffold generate itself. when i run my code on browser it shows following error:

```
 NoMethodError in Users#index

Showing /home/wasif/projects/club/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #12):

9:     <th></th>
10:   </tr>
11: 
12: <% @users.each do |user| %>
13:   <tr>
14:     <td><%= user.name %></td>
15:     <td><%= user.contact %></td>
```

This is the code of `users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = user.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @User = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /user/new
  # GET /user/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /user/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

I dont know what to do now, and how can i remove error, as i m beginner so please help me what to do now. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Show your `users_controller.rb` please.

Comment: U r missing something in your controller code.paste the `UsersController` Code Here.

Comment: did you run 'rake db:migrate' ?

Comment: i have edited my code.. now u can see my user_controller code above.
... i run rake db:migrate many times.

Comment: Ruby is case sensitive! `User != user` Also, your use of `@user` vs `@users` is not consistent. Try to fix those mistakes and see if it works.

Comment: It's also `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, not `accepted`. There's no excuse for not copying and pasting the correct code.

Comment: @Mischa i think its my typing mistake... i haven't copy paste my code... as i typed that all myself... everything is fine `@user` vs `@users` is consistent and its perfectly correct where to use `User`, `Users`, `user`, `users` all accros.

Comment: Try running your rails console in your terminal and run this command rails c then do User.first and User.all are you able to see all your records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have wrong code in index method:

`@users = User.all` should be used instead of `@users = user.all`

```
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I am also wondering. user.all should have given u an error. hmmm.

Comment: user.all is my typing mistake... its perfectly fine User.all in the code... but having same error.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the DB and make sure you have column "user_id" in table "events"